# Send a numpad key (with Num Lock off)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to test how my app reacts to numpad keys. I found in https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/ specs that for example for Numpad Home (with location = `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD` = `3`) a symbol `\uE057` should be used. However, it doesn't work for me: I get Home with default location (`0`), moreover, `event.code` is empty. It gives me a different result when I physically press NUMPAD7 button with Num Lock off: it that case, I get correct location `3` and `event.code` is `Numpad7`.

```java
var options = FirefoxOptions();
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
var driver = FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to("https://keycode.info/");
driver.findElementByTagName("body").sendKeys("\uE057");
```

So how can I send such a key? I'm now thinking of manual recording of generated events when I physically press a key, and then sending these events via Selenium's execution of JS script. However, I haven't tried it yet; maybe there is a better way to do it in Selenium; maybe there is another framework that allows it better.

By the way, I've filed a [similar ticket in geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1854) because it looks like a bug of webdriver to me...

Comment: Are you sure that's right element to send key to?

Comment: @DMart, yep, I'm sure about `body` element: I see keyboard listeners there. Actually, you can check it yourself quite easily, so I don't understand why you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

`\ue01d` is the unicode for NUmberpad3

python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://keycode.info/")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys("\ue01d")
input()
```

you can use https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/latest/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html to send keys instead of sending unicode directly

In firefox this is will work if you use action chain:

```
 ActionChains.send_keys("\ue01d").perform()
```

Comment: For "\ue01d", I get `event.key=Unidentified` so it's definitely not what I want :) And as of Keys, I'm aware of them. If you mean they can be used in my case, could you give an example? I just can't find Numpad Home there...

Comment: i tried and it worked as expected , could you add the cod you tried ?

Comment: The same code as in the question, but with "\uE057" replaced to "\ue01d". And what do you get?

Comment: added the python code please try it and let me know , if it works then will check for nodejs

Comment: ok so it works in CHrome but not in firefox , let me check why

Comment: Yep, works in Chrome for me. However, it's not what I want. Firstly, I need `event.location` not `0` (as for general keys) but `3` (as for numpad keys). Secondly, I need not 3 on Numpad (like when Num Lock is on and NUMPAD3 is pressed) but Page Down on Numpad (like when Num Lock is off and NUMPAD3 is pressed).

Comment: For firefox you can use actionchains